# PHP - Fatal Error - Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() - mbstring is installed

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mbstring

I'm receiving an error message whilst trying to access PHPMyAdmin on IIS 7.5. I've checked phpinfo and have the following information for mbstring;

```
Multibyte Support: enabled
Multibyte string engine: libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation: disabled
libmbfl version: 1.3.2

mbstring.detect_order: no value
mbstring.encoding_translation: Off
mbstring.func_overload: 0
mbstring.http_input: pass
mbstring.http_output: pass
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes: ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding: no value
mbstring.language: neutral
mbstring.strict_detection: Off
mbstring.substitute_character: no value
```

As far as I understand this means that mbstring has been installed. I know a lot of people have asked the question on here before, but the only response seems to be install mbstring. Looking at the above, this has already been installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204437/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding

Comment: I also have the gd application installed..