# Cannot access phpmyadmin in apache server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I have followed this tutorial for installation of php, mysql, apache and phpmyadmin :http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZ2zbO6PABk
and towards the end when he tried to access phpmyadmin he got the following error but resolved it :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on
>   line 177

I am now still having issue. Like this question:

[Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204437/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding)

I have also made sure ive uncommented out and unblocked the following extensions:

> extension=php_gd2.dll
>
> extension=php_mbstring.dll
>
> extension=php_exif.dll
>
> extension=php_mysql.dll
>
> extension=php_mysqli.dll

What else am I missing?

Comment: Do `print_r(get_loaded_extensions());` to check if these "uncommented" extensions are loaded or not.

Comment: Did you already restart apache and check that all required modules are loaded via `phpinfo();`?

Comment: Looks like the MultiByte extension isn't loaded. Make sure you have the DLL file, then restart Apache and use `phpinfo()` to check whether your extensions are loading.

Comment: sorry im pretty new at this. where do i do `print_r(get_loaded_extensions());` and `phpinfo();`

Comment: @MohammadReza it does look like those extensions are not loaded. `Array ( [0] => Core [1] => bcmath [2] => calendar [3] => ctype [4] => date [5] => ereg [6] => filter [7] => ftp [8] => hash [9] => iconv [10] => json [11] => mcrypt [12] => SPL [13] => odbc [14] => pcre [15] => Reflection [16] => session [17] => standard [18] => mysqlnd [19] => tokenizer [20] => zip [21] => zlib [22] => libxml [23] => dom [24] => PDO [25] => Phar [26] => SimpleXML [27] => wddx [28] => xml [29] => xmlreader [30] => xmlwriter [31] => apache2handler [32] => mhash )` what could i do to make it load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

added `PHPINIDir "C:\php"` in http.conf and it now works

Comment: Surprisingly, but this is the only solution, that solved my problem in the whole SO))) Thank you)

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too. The problem is that settings in PHP.INI is no incorrect. Mysql is not longer enabled by default. you got to enable the dll in the PHP.INI among other dlls.

http://www.hirokoymj.com/Install_phpMyAdmin.php

These are some of the dlls that you have to uncomment in php.ini
curl, gd2, mysql, mqsqli, mbstring, pdo_mysql, phar, soap, zip

It works like a charm after having changed the settings!

Answer (score 0):

On my install I found that the 4 instructions lines above the 'extension_dir="C:/..." entry in the php.ini file were not properly commented out. So nothing after that in the config file seemed to work. Including the set path to the extension_dir. So the mbstring.dll wasn't loading. I added semi-colons to comment them out, restarted Apache, and Viola! The hirokoymj.com page listed above was a big help!