# Php Arabic file saving in windows 7

Tags: php

In php and windows7 as OS file saving as arabic name it gives like this Ù…Ø´Ø±Ø´Ù‰ØºØ´.I need save the file name with the arabic text only.

```
header("Content-Type:text/html;  charset=utf-8"); 
$name = $_GET['name'];
if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] )) 
{
$filename = $name.".png";
file_put_contents($filename,$GLOBALS[ 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' ]);
}
```

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
header("Content-Type:text/html;  charset=utf-8"); 
$name = $_GET['name'];
if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] )) 
{
  $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($name);
  $filename = iconv($encoding, "UTF-8", $name.".png");
  file_put_contents($filename,$GLOBALS[ 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' ]);
}
```

Comment: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding().@Muhammet

Comment: @vamsikr Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204437/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding