# php - Have trouble installing phpmyadmin on PHP7 Apache/2.4.7 on windows 7

Tags: php, windows-7, apache2.4

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc:177 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc(282): _encode('The %s extensio...') #1 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc(289): _gettext('The %s extensio...') #2 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\core.lib.php(306): __('The %s extensio...') #3 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\core.lib.php(957): PMA_warnMissingExtension('mbstring', true) #4 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php(102): PMA_checkExtensions() #5 C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\index.php(13): require_once('C:\Apache24\htd...') #6 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177

Comment: Could you add all relevant code?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The error is clearly enough.. you must add the `mbstring` extension in apache

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem after I had installed on windows PHP7, MySql, Apache and PhpMyAdmin.
The solution was to add in the `php.ini` file:
`extension_dir = "c:/php7/ext"`
I was helped by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25301739/3548935
Make sure that you also uncomment this line in the `php.ini` file as well:
`extension=php_mbstring.dll`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue i just update full extension folder path like this

```
extension_dir = "C:/wamp/bin/php/php7.1.13/ext/"
```

and updated latest phpmyadmin version because phpmyadmin4.1.14 is not compatible with php7. i wish it will resolve your problem