# PhpMyAdmin, PHP7, MariaDB10, Apache2.4, Windows 10

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, windows-10, mariadb, php-7

I tried to manually install latest version of Apache,PHP7 with MariaDB on a Windows 10 machine, and when i try to run latest phpmyadmin setup script, it return:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\Server\Web\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc:177 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\Server\Web\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc(282): _encode('The %s extensio...') 
#1 C:\Server\Web\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc(289): _gettext('The %s extensio...') 
#2 C:\Server\Web\phpmyadmin\libraries\core.lib.php(306): __('The %s extensio...') 
#3 C:\Server\Web\phpmyadmin\libraries\core.lib.php(961): PMA_warnMissingExtension('mbstring', true) 
#4 C:\Server\Web\phpmyadmin\libraries\common.inc.php(102): PMA_checkExtensions() 
#5 C:\Server\Web\phpmyadmin\index.php(13): require_once('C:\\Server\\Web\\p...') 
#6 {main} thrown in C:\Server\Web\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb\_detect\_encoding()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204437/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

It is wamp, I am sure you must be having `mbstring` library, just make sure `extension=php_mbstring.dll` is not commented in your `php.ini`

[image]

Comment: the extension extension=php_mbstring.dll is uncommented

Comment: echo phpinfo(); can you see that?

Comment: <blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/ET8JB"><a href="//imgur.com/ET8JB"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You need to install or enable the `php-mbstring` library.

Have a look at the `phpinfo()` and check if that module is enabled. After installing / enabling it make sure the Apache service is restarted.

```
mbstring

Multibyte Support => enabled 
Multibyte string engine => libmbfl 
HTTP input encoding translation => disabled 
libmbfl version => 1.3.2 oniguruma version => 5.9.6
```

http://php.net/manual/it/install.windows.extensions.php

Comment: it seems php-mbstring not appearing in phpinfo() , even is uncommented

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it seems the

> extension_dir = "ext"

isn't conffigured corectly now it's working :D Thanks!