# error while upgrading php 5.6.3 to 7.1.1 on xampp

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, php-7.1

I have trouble while upgrading php 5.6.3 to php 7.1.1 on xampp.

Browser showed error log while I try open http://localhost/phpmyadmin/:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc:177 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc(279): _encode('Error') #1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc(286): _gettext('Error') #2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\core.lib.php(235): __('Error') #3 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\core.lib.php(308): PMA_fatalError('The [a@./url.ph...') #4 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php(90): PMA_warnMissingExtension('mbstring', true) #5 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php(12): require_once('C:\xampp\phpMyA...') #6 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb\_detect\_encoding()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204437/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17204437/276648 You're missing an extension. You probably just need to enable it in your PHP config.