# Php 5.3.29 Linux Ubuntu 14.04 Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_order

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have a PHP error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_order

while running my code on Linux Ubuntu 14.04, php version 5.3.29.
In php.info file I have the configuration for mbstring library as shown below:

[image]

Does anybody, please, have a solution for that problem?

P.s I cannot update php version to a newer one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204437/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)