# Trying to use khanamiryan's php-qrcode-detector-decoder on apache2 / php7

Tags: php, qr-code

I am trying to use khanamiryan's php library for reading QR codes from image files;
https://github.com/khanamiryan/php-qrcode-detector-decoder

Currently I am unable to get it working on Debian Stretch (specifically Raspbian Stretch on a Raspberry Pi 3B). I can only get HTTP 500 errors.

Clean install of Raspbian Stretch, then the following in a terminal;

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php php7.0-gd composer
cd /var/www/html
composer require khanamiryan/qrcode-detector-decoder
```

Here's the php I am trying to run;

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$qrcode = new QrReader('test.png');
$text = $qrcode->text();
print($text);
?>
```

Expected result is the text from the QR code in the image test.png is written to the response but I always get HTTP 500 error.

Any suggestions? Do I need to install some underlying C++ or Java library?

Comment: Have you checked the output of your web server log file (for apache2, generally at /var/log/apache2/error.log). In general you can found more information why the PHP script fails...

Comment: Yes I'm getting this;
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'QrReader' not found in /var/www/html/index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 3

Comment: Sounds like you need to add QrReader to the autoload, or possibly use the full namespace for the class name.

Comment: Aha, progress. I added the line `use Zxing\QrReader;` and now I have this error output

(too long to fit in this comment)

Comment: Use a backslash for namespace, i.e.: `use Zxing\QrReader;`

Comment: Thanks yes I did use the backslash, here's the error output I am getting now - it looks like it's coming from within the library code https://pastebin.com/2FSzDZHM

Comment: have a look at: [fatal error mb_detect_encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204437/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding)

Comment: Lovelace, that was it - you're a legend. Thank you so much! o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add namespace line `use Zxing\QrReader;`

```php
<?php
use Zxing\QrReader;
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$qrcode = new QrReader('test.png');
$text = $qrcode->text();
print($text);
?>
```

Also run this in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```