# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in Uniform Server with PHP 7.2

Tags: php, php-7.2, uniform-server

I'm using [Uniform Server](https://uniformserver.com) with PHP 7.2 and upon running a php page I made I get this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding()

When I try to enable the `mbstring` php module (and other modules) through the graphical user interface I get this.

[image: can't use the gui to enable or disable php module in php 7.2 for uniform server]

So when I do it manually, my `php_production.ini` looks like this. I have used Uniform Server to select that php settings file.

```
extension=gd2
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
```

So why do I still get the error if I have enabled the modules manually via the text editor?

[Here is my phpinfo.](https://desbest.com/phpinfo%20on%20php%207.2%20uniform%20server.htm)

Below is the contents of `C:\Users\Documents\UniServerZ\core\php72\extensions`

[image: php 7.2 extensions in uniform server]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb\_detect\_encoding()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204437/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding)

Comment: I have tried out all the answers on that question and none of them help me. For starters, I'm using windows not linux, the module dll files are not read only, replacing forward slashes with back slashes doesn't help, I have the gd module installed, and mbstring should be installed when I un-comment the line out, but it's not.

Comment: Have you seen the ticket in the uniform server forums? http://forum.uniformserver.com/topic/2731-mbstring-problem/

Comment: I've just looked at it now and that thread isn't helpful to me as the OP there is using php on the command line, and I am not. I have no need to change the `php-cli.ini` file as I'm not using the command line.

Comment: When using PHP 7.2 `mbstring` is nowhere to be found in `phpinfo()` but when using PHP 7.1 `mbstring` can be found. In PHP 7.1 it says `Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring ` and the `mbstring` module appears. I need that to happen for PHP 7.2

Comment: In fact on PHP 7.2 I can't make any php module load, whether that be curl, mbstring, or anything else, except for the default ones.

Comment: Here it is. https://desbest.com/phpinfo%20on%20php%207.2%20uniform%20server.htm

Comment: Sorry I gave you the wrong web page. I've updated the web page. Click the link again.

Comment: PHP 7.2 also isn't loading the `mysqli` module so I can't even work with databases.

Comment: Please update your question with a directory breakdown of what's in `C:/Users/desbest/Documents/UniServerZ/core/php72/extensions` I am thinking this is a permissions related issue, since you installed under `C:/Users/desbest/Documents/UniServerZ`, which typically does not have the permissions for the user that is executing PHP or the webserver. I recommend using `C:/UniServerZ` instead and assigning the appropriate permissions.

Comment: How do I check whether the permissions are set, and how do I set permissions. Also PHP 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.3, and 7.4 work, it's just that 7.2 does not, so it doesn't look like `UniServerZ` being in `My Documents` being an issue.

Comment: I've updated the question to show the contents of `C:/Users/desbest/Documents/UniServerZ/core/php72/extensions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer of Uniform Server managed to fix the problem, saying so in [this post](http://forum.uniformserver.com/topic/3614-i-cannot-choose-the-modules-on-php-72/?do=findComment&comment=13012).

> Ok.. Thanks for bringing this up.. Looks like made a mistake on the spelling on the extensions folder. Please rename the /core/php72/**extentions** to /core/php72/**extensions** and everything should work as expected.. I have updated the module in Sourceforge.