# XAMPP Call to undefined function

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

Fatal error while opening phpmyadmin and browser showing blank page while accessing wp-admin.

The exact error is

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177
```

My path is `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`

The other part of this error is while accessing wp-admin page that shows no error but a blank page.

path `http://localhost/eCommerce/wp-admin/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb\_detect\_encoding()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204437/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding)

Comment: Please refer to :
[Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\apache\htdocs\phpmyadmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271260/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding-in-c-apache-htdocs) Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Open your `php.ini` file , `"extension_dir"` line looked like following :

```
extension_dir = "C:/xampp/bin/php/php7/ext/"
```

which i changed to :

```
extension_dir = "C:\xampp\bin\php\php7\ext\"
```