# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\Users\Jarek\mywebsite\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to set up phpMyAdmin, and i was following this [site](http://www.premiumwebbloghosting.com/2012/04/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-windows-7.html) , but i got an error about "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\Users\Jarek\mywebsite\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177", and i searched this error online, Most of suggestion are uncommon some lines in php.ini, but it didn't work for me.
This is the site tell you how to solve problem with this error. 
[solve 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351635/php-fatal-error-when-trying-to-access-phpmyadmin-mb-detect-encoding) 
[solve 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271260/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding-in-c-apache-htdocs)

php.ini is in my php folder which is located in c diver.
[image]

prompt command to check path
[image]

Every time i changed config, i also did restart apache.

[image: This is where i uncommon the lines]

I also tried to write some piece of code of php as below:

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","xxxxxxx","morris_db");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
```

and open my browser, and type localhost/index.php, it shows me an error about "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Users\Jarek\mywebsite\index.php on line 8"

Comment: Try `echo file_get_contents(php_ini_loaded_file());` to see that your chosen INI file is in fact being loaded.

Comment: May i ask what information in the content to know if my ini file being loaded, because there were a lot of stuff inside.

Comment: Does it have all of your `extension` lines?

Comment: I just search all of extension in that content, and all of my extension are uncommon in that content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these extensions in the PHP.ini

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Also check whether the PHP folder exists in the PATH.

Comment: atleast try to read the question completely, what he has posted in image

Comment: Did you check the path from the command prompt ? Is PHP there in the path ?

Comment: I am sorry. what path is it?  A path of PHP.ini?

Comment: Open command prompt and type PATH and press enter. Check whether the path has the folder in which PHP is installed, say C:\PHP .

Comment: Check the php.ini file whether it has extension_dir="C:/PHP/ext";

Comment: No, its only extension_dir = "ext", but i set up the path as C:\php alrady, do i still have to put C:/PHP before /ext??

Comment: I think it needs the exact path. As my file had extension_dir = "F:\xampp\php\ext";

Comment: Yes, you are right. Problem solved. It has to put C:/PHP/ext instead of "ext", I was thinking because i already set up the path as C:\php. Thank you so much.