# How to upgrade PHP 5.3.28 to PHP 5.5x in Windows 7

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Following is the configuration of my Machine:

```
PHP 5.3.28
MySQL 5.0.8
Apache 2.2.13
```

I've configured these manually without using Wamp/Lamp and now I want to upgrade PHP 5.3.28 to PHP 5.5.22.

What step I need to follow for doing this migration?
Do I need to update apache and mysql as well?

I need proper (step-by-step) solutions for this so that it'll work properly after migration.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple way :http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.5

Just extract it into some folder (say, C:\PHP), and add the bin folder to your PATH (if you want - most people do).

[REFERENCE](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,120383,120475)

Comment: I extracted files now its showing error `Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, localhost@localhost.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.`

Comment: Resolved it. But now I'm getting error while opening phpmyadmin "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in D:\www\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177"

Comment: @CWC15 this is because your some extension blocked.try below link,it will solve your problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271260/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding-in-c-apache-htdocs  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351635/php-fatal-error-when-trying-to-access-phpmyadmin-mb-detect-encoding    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204437/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-detect-encoding